# How can insert icons inside on status bar menu in xcode Objective-c like airport

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I was wondering how to insert icons on a menubar item like apples airport signal status, what are the requirements for that to do so?

My code looks like:

```
NSMenu *menu = [[NSMenu alloc] init];
[menu addItemWithTitle:@"itemTitle" action:someFunction keyEquivalent:@""];
 _statusItem.menu = menu;
```

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tnl6c.png)

Comment: If you intend to place an icon to the right of a menu item, it's not going to be easy.  If you just want an icon to the left, it can be done with several lines of code.

Comment: i means to the right of list, like airport icons.
any idea?

Comment: A possible duplicate...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163503/how-to-add-icons-to-the-right-hand-side-of-nsmenuitem

Comment: wow. thank you, thats exactly what i want!